# Having two ng-controller with angularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my JS file

```
var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', []);
camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/camera/list').then(function(response) {
            $scope.records= response.data; 
        });
  }]);
camListApp.controller('Hello2',['$scope', function($scope){
    $scope.custom = true;
    $scope.toggleCustom = function() {
       $scope.custom = ! $scope.custom;
    };
}]);
```

This is my Html file

```
<html ng-app='camListApp'>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"> 
</script>
<script src="hello.js"></script>
<title>Image downloader </title>
</head>


<body>
<h3>Search by cameraid:</h3><br>
<select ng-model="searchBox" style="width:25%">
<option value="000000006f4280af">000000006f4280af</option>
<option value="002">002</option>
<option value="0011">0011</option>
</select>


<div ng-controller="Hello">
<br>
 <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>

        <th>CamID</th>
        <th>Timestamp</th>
        <th>View Image</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="record in records | filter:searchBox">

        <td>{{record.cameraid}}</td>
        <td>{{record.timestamp}}</td>
        <div ng-controller="Hello2">
         <td><button ng-click="toggleCustom()">View</button></td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
   </table>
   <span ng-hide="custom">From:
        <input type="text" id="from" />
    </span>
    <span ng-show="custom"></span>
 </div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can i have two controllers to work in an app? As i cannot find any way for them to work at the same time. The first controller is to consume my web service with angularjs but this is able to work and i added another controller that is using toggle a button to show and hide.

Comment: `div` is not a valid element in a `tr`. Also, are there any console errors?

Comment: like @devqon wrote, your html is not valid, you don't even close your div with ng-controller

Comment: So where should i put the div?

Comment: lose the div, just put the `ng-controller` on the `td` for example

Comment: I closed but still not working. @kTT

Comment: @AlvinWee you are probably out of scope when reaching custom variable.

Comment: @BryanEuton  i tried put in td also can't work

Comment: Its working fine. Can you explain in detail, what exactly the issue is?

Comment: @Rohit i manage i solve my problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several issues with your code. First of all, `div` is not a valid element as a child of a `tr`, so lose that one.

Secondly, your `custom` property is outside of your second controller if you maintain the current scoping:

```
<!-- the Hello2 controller and its scope is only available on the td 
itself and its children. You use your 'custom' property outside of this,
so that won't work -->
<td ng-controller="Hello2"><button ng-click="toggleCustom()">View</button></td>
```

Looking at your scoping you should just only use the first controller, and put the code on that one:

```
var camListApp = angular.module('camListApp', []);
camListApp.controller('Hello', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http){

    $scope.custom = true;
    $scope.toggleCustom = function() {
       $scope.custom = ! $scope.custom;
    };
    $http.get('http://localhost:8080/camera/list').then(function(response) {
            $scope.records= response.data; 
        });
  }]);
```

Comment: So how should i put the code in my first controller?

Comment: It works! i just remove the second controller and follow your method.!

Answer (score 0):

## read the documentation first - [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller)

---

the answer to your question is - **no**, your *.html* file may have one controller

but if you wish to reuse your logics, it's done via factories and services - [angularjs docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers)

another must-read: [angularjs good practice](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide/blob/master/a1/README.md)

---

so let's apply that on your code

**app.js**

```
angular

    .module('camListApp', []);
```

**myCtl.controller.js**

```
angular

    .module('camListApp')
    .controller('myCtl', myCtl);

function myCtl($scope, myFactory) {

    var vm = this;
    vm.doSomething = myFactory.someFactoryFunction;

}
```

**myFactory.factory.js**

```
angular

    .module('camListApp')
    .factory('myFactory', myFactory);

function myFactory($http) {

    return {
        someFactoryFunction: retrieveSomeData
    };

    function retrieveSomeData() {

        $http.get('http://localhost:8080/camera/list')

        .then(success)
        .catch(error);

        function success(response) {
            return response.data;
        }

        function error(response) {
            // handle error
        }

    }

}
```

**view.html**

```
...
<div ng-controller="myCtl">
    <button ng-click="vm.doSomething()">View</button>
</div>
...
```

not sure if the code above is *100% working*, didn't try it out, but the logic stays the same